# RoR Active record 'where' doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code, the first part is the problem, and the second is perfectly working.

```
def show
  if @user.cooker?
    @pushs = @user.pushs.where(taked_by = @user.id)
  else 
    @pushs = @user.pushs
  end
end
```

Well the code say, if I'm a cooker, I want to display all the push where the variable :taked_by is has the same id than my user.id

And the second par say that if I'm not a cooker, display all my own push.

Comment: `where(taked_by: @user.id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `taked_by: @user.id` or `:taked_by => @user.id`

```
def show
  if @user.cooker?
    @pushs = @user.pushs.where(taked_by: @user.id)
  else 
    @pushs = @user.pushs
  end
end
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks Kumar Abinash, well there is no more errors anymore, but the function is not running. I would like display push when his :taked_by == @user.id . Do you have a way to write that ?

Comment: No, what it does is, stores all the `pushs` in `@pushs` where the taked_by is equals to @user.id. Further more the that line is only executed when @user.cooker? is `true`. You may try it in rails console to verify.

Comment: Oh, Ok, well I changed "@pushs = @user.pushs.where(taked_by: @user.id)" into 
"@pushs = Push.where(taked_by: @user.id)". So now is searching into all the push and not only his own Push. So thanks a lot for this explainations. Have a great day !!